# Closed laptop lid last night, today it can't boot up

Tags: macos

I fell asleep to a movie playing last night and woke up to just shut the laptop lid like I always do. To my knowledge I don't have any updates running at certain times or anything.

Today I open the laptop and it looks like it's at some type of loading screen. Next thing you know it says OSInstall.mpkg appears to be missing or damaged.

I always just shut the lid on my laptop at night so I don't know why last night was any different. Do I have to reinstall MacOS on my laptop or is there a way to repair? There are no repair options in MacOS Utilities other than just restore from backup and reinstall.

Comment: Did you d/l some High Sierra Dev Beta installer previously?

Comment: Not sure but I ended up going into recovery and accessing the terminal. Cleared up 20gb of space going from 6gb to 26gb and rebooted. All is well now. Very weird.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it must have been something space related. I went into recovery and cleared up 20gb of space (had 6gb previously) and rebooted. Everything was well upon reboot.